# Reroute link to domain base to specified directory

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess, src

I have a method, where users can create their own files. Their files are located at `/users/<username>/files/<files>`. The problem is, when the user does something like `<script src="/javascript.js"></script>`, it links to `/javascript.js`. What I want it to do, however, is to instead link to `/users/<username/files/javascript.js`. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: whats the file location of the file your calling it from?

Comment: say `/users/<username>/files/file.html`. Remember, this is only an example, because the users can manipulate the files.

Comment: are you passing a username identity or storing one in a session? If so

/users/<?php echo $username ?>/files/javascript.js

and just use /users/<?php echo $username ?>/files/ as a header before any file call.

Comment: It's stored in a session.

Comment: or just replace what ive said with a session variable.

Comment: Again, I cannot control what they write, so I cannot put `<? echo $username ?>`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting

```
<base href="/users/<username>/files/">
```

in the document head?

Comment: Users can edit the files, I have no control over the document head.